# What type of connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone identify this connector type?

[image: Connector]

Comment: I last remember seeing those used as speaker connectors about 20-30 years ago ... Don't know what they're called though.

Comment: -1 for dumping the ridiculously large uncropped picture on us.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Tried to fix the picture. Cropped it and reduced it to 25%. Should show up when my edit is approved.

Answer (score 8):

It's [DIN speaker connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector). Pretty old one..
[image]

Comment: I had a desk lamp that was connecting to the 12VAC power supply using this kind of connector. So, I would say that the use is not limited to speakers.

Comment: @Naz Well, I have seen systems powered with a 3.5mm audio jack and even RF antenna cables. People do strange things sometimes.

Comment: Ikea are one of those strange people. They use them extensively for connecting into wall warts for lamps.

Comment: @Majenko I am not saying it is wrong. Are you familiar with the name "kettle plug"? Well, it is not used just for kettles.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The "kettle plug" differs from the similar IEC C13 connector with which it is often confused.  The "kettle plug" has a notch in it, but the C13 doesn't. You can use a "kettle plug" in a C13 socket, but not the other way around. C13 are often only as little as 6A, but the kettle plugs are 13A, so it would be safe to use a kettle plug in an C13 socket, but not the other way around - hence the notch.

Comment: @Majenko Not quite.  IEC 60320 C15/C16 notch denotes 'hot condition' connectors with higher temperature rating.  They have the same 10A current rating as C13/C14.  For example see [the Wikipedia IEC 60320 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320)

Comment: @rolinger I sit corrected.